# How to: find package on Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm trying to install a Kali package on Ubuntu (Kali and Cyborg don't properly allow you to install certain updates the way Ubuntu does, though I like Cyborg's style) called ldb (load balancing detector).

I've found https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ldb which is awesome (I love all things Ubuntu, genuinely) but I can't work out from the page how to find the `apt install` package name.

Could someone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Choose the folder you want to use for **Load Balancing Indicator**
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
3. Type `cd /path/to/lbdfolder`
4. Type `wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/craig/ge.mine.nu/master/lbd/lbd.sh`
5. Type `chmod +x lbd.sh`
6. Usage `./lbd.sh domain [port] {https}`

Comment: `e: unable to locate package ldb-tools` e.g. already tried that

Comment: What ubuntu version you are using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Standard.

Comment: I will update my answer

Comment: I think it may have been a typo on my part. Just a second.

Comment: I updated check my answer

Comment: Good edit though. I am impressed. You might want to add the original answer as well as there was nothing wrong with it.

Comment: LDB is an an embedded LDAP-Like database library, so the answer would be wrong.